# accessing storyboard from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UINavigationController that pushes a view controller 3 levels down. I am trying to access the story board from the third UIViewController and I can't. Is there a global way in which I can access the storyboard from any UIViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the current storyboard through the `storyboard` property of any View controller.  Ex.:

```
self.storyboard;
```

**EDIT**

In the event that `self.storyboard` is not set for some reason, you can always get the storyboard by calling

```
+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil
```

Comment: so when I tried doing:

[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PNRProfileViewController"]

it gives me nil.. when I do:

[self.parentViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PNRProfileViewController"]

then it works

Comment: Hm, in this case is `self` a view controller that has been instantiated from the storyboard?

Comment: any idea why it's behaving like this?

Comment: yes...self is a view controller instantiated from the storyboard.. but from that view controller how do I access storyboard

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but you're not the first person i've talked to that has had this problem.  I edited my answer above to hopefully contain a solution to your problem

Comment: The question is where you do it. the storyboard instance is, as far as I figured it out, just set after a viewDidLoad. did you try it in you viewWillAppear or later?

Comment: I did this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath for a tableView

Answer (score 0):

What about `thirdViewController.navigationController.storyboard` ?